# qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display :0 qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found

Tags: python, c++, linux, windows, openfoam

I'm trying to install OpenFOAM software on my laptop. I have Windows 10 Home OS version 2004. To use OpenFOAM on Windows, I installed Windows Subsystem for Linux (File version 10.0.19041.1023) on my laptop. Then, to install OpenFOAM, I followed these commands in the WSL-

```
sudo sh -c "wget -O - http://dl.openfoam.org/gpg.key | apt-key add -"

sudo add-apt-repository http://dl.openfoam.org/ubuntu

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install openfoam8

sudo apt-get install build-essential

echo ". /opt/openfoam-dev/etc/bashrc" >> $HOME/ .bashrc

. $HOME/.bashrc

simpleFoam -help

echo "export DISPLAY=:0" >> ${HOME}/.bashrc

. $HOME/.bashrc

sudo apt-get install gedit gedit-plugins

sudo apt-get install gnuplot gnuplot-x11 gnuplot-doc libgd-tools

sudo apt-get install mplayer mencoder

gedit &
```

Here, I got the output as -

```
[1] 21180
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(gedit:21180): Gtk-WARNING **: 16:58:05.730: cannot open display: :0

[1]+  Exit 1                  gedit
```

Then I entered -

```
of8
```

and got the output as -

```
Command 'of8' not found, did you mean:

  command 'os8' from deb os8 (2.1-7)
  command 'ofl' from deb hxtools (20200126-1build1)

Try: sudo apt install <deb name>
```

So then I tried to install it -

```
mkdir -p $FOAM_RUN
cd $FOAM_RUN
cp -r $FOAM_TUTORIALS .
cd tutorials/incompressible/icoFoam/cavity/cavity
blockMesh
```

Then -

```
icoFoam
```

Then in order to open ParaFOAM, I did this -

```
paraFoam
```

But it is giving me the error -
"
Created temporary 'cavity.OpenFOAM'
qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display :0
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, xcb.
"

In order to fix this, I tried doing this -

```
/platforms$ ldd libqxcb.so

sudo apt-get install libx11-xcb1

paraFoam
```

But it is still giving me the error -
"
Created temporary 'cavity.OpenFOAM'
qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display :0
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, xcb.

Aborted
"

I also tried -

```
s

apt installclibxkbcommon-x11-0

sudo apt install libxkbcommon-x11-0
```

This gives the output -

"
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
libxkbcommon-x11-0 is already the newest version (0.10.0-1).
libxkbcommon-x11-0 set to manually installed.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 91 not upgraded.
"

And then when I again try the command *paraFoam* , it is still giving me the error -
"
Created temporary 'cavity.OpenFOAM'
qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display :0
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, xcb.
"

I don't know what to do now. Can anyone please help me install this software ?..

Comment: This is probably more appropriate to superuser.com, since it is not a programming question. Make sure you read the site guidelines there though. Also, before applying any tags, read their description as well.

Comment: Which version of WSL? is it WSL2? You are installing openfoam-dev and trying to invoke an alias for OpenFOAM8.

Comment: I had to `export QT_QPA_PLATFORM=offscreen` in my Github Actions (no screen) while facing this problem.